# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, distutils

I am trying to install pip using the command:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

but I get this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

Although when I run `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils`
It says that it's installed and the newest version

Comment: Which python version are you running?

Comment: Python 3.6.9 this is the default version when I type pyhton3 --version

Comment: `which python3` vs `sudo which python3` ? `python3 --version` vs `sudo python3 --version` ?

Comment: the same one 3.6.9